# Drawing Spirograph patterns using non-circular inner wheels

Tags: tikz-pgf

[Spirograph patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirograph) are plotted by a point in a "circular" wheel moving along a ring.

Is it possible to edit the Spirograph code from the answer to  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521684/drawing-spirograph-patterns) to use a non-circular inner wheel (for example an elliptical wheel) instead of the inner circular wheel). The next photo shows some of the non-cirular inner wheels used in the commercial Spirograph toy.

[image]

The left inner wheel produces these drawings

[image]

The following is the basic Spirograph code I am referring to [from this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521684/drawing-spirograph-patterns).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{pics/spiro/.style={code={
\tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions]
 plot[variable=\t,domain=0:2*pi*\pv{nRotations}, samples=90*\pv{nRotations}+1, smooth cycle]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
);
}},
spiro/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1,nRotations/.initial=1}
\begin{frame}[t] 
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.4mm]
\pic[draw,blue,fill=blue!40,scale=.7]{spiro={R=6,r=-1.5,p=1.52}}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces this simple figure

[image]

Comment: I think you might want to add a bit more information. The graph can be obtained by patching segments of the basic spiro graph together. Basically you need to draw n times a fraction 1/N of the basic graph. I am wondering in which form you want to specify the data.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat In your code you specified the path of a point inside a moving circle. Is there a way to edit the code so that the path of the point could be specified inside a moving oval shape! I have no mathematical background. So, I wonder can that be done.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat If I understand correctly, a circle has one axis, but an oval (ellipse) has 2 axes. So, in your code, point p inside the circle is moving with one relation to its centre represented by (r); but in an ellipse, its movement has 2 relations. If my understanding is right, you have to specify 2 (r)s.

Comment: To me it seems that these are not ovals, i.e. no ellipses, but segments of larger circles patched together. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I can not argue with you; because, as I`ve said, I have no mathematical background. With your point of view, could it be done. I mean modifying the code to utilize these wheel types. Or could it be modified to use a point inside a moving ellipse instead of a circle.

Comment: I think one may obtain the depicted graphs much easier using decorations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal to get something of the sort.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[decoration={coil,aspect=0.25,segment length=pi*1cm/10.75},decorate]
  (0,0) arc[start angle=-60,end angle=60,radius=3cm]
  arc[start angle=120,end angle=240,radius=3cm];
 \draw[decoration={coil,aspect=0.25,segment length=pi*0.75cm/10.75},decorate]
  (7,1) arc[start angle=-15,end angle=75,radius=3cm]
  arc[start angle=105,end angle=195,radius=3cm]
  arc[start angle=225,end angle=315,radius=3cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I fully understand that this is not perfect. However, to create something better, one needs clear prescriptions. In the previous questions of yours on this subject, there was a clear prescription that yielded a smooth graph. Here I see some corners, and one can only smoothen it out in an unambiguous way if there is some prescription.

One proposal in this direction is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/narcs/.style={code={
 \tikzset{spiro/.cd,#1}
 \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro/##1}} 
\draw plot[variable=\t,trig format=rad,domain=0:{2*pi*0.99},smooth
cycle,samples=15*\pv{S}]
({\pv{R}*cos(\t/\pv{S}-pi/(\pv{S}*\pv{S})
    +(\pv{S}-1)*2*pi*int(\pv{S}*\t/(2*pi))/(\pv{S}*\pv{S}))
    -\pv{R}*cos(pi/4)*cos(2*pi*int(\pv{S}*\t/(2*pi))/\pv{S})},
 {\pv{R}*sin(\t/\pv{S}-pi/(\pv{S}*\pv{S})
 +(\pv{S}-1)*2*pi*int(\pv{S}*\t/(2*pi))/(\pv{S}*\pv{S}))
 -\pv{R}*cos(pi/4)*sin(2*pi*int(\pv{S}*\t/(2*pi))/\pv{S})});}},
 spiro/.cd,R/.initial=3,S/.initial=2]
 \path pic{narcs}  (5,0) pic{narcs={S=3}}
 (10,0) pic{narcs={S=4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I keep it mainly for my own records.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I did not mean to draw the ellipse. I meant using an inner ellipse instead of an inner circle to draw a Spirograph.

Comment: @Hany Yes, adding the cycloid or spiro graph is easy if one has the base curve. I understand that this is only the first step. But I do not know what you precisely want to achieve.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Using an elliptical inner wheel instead of an inner circle gives interesting Spirograph patterns. I wonder if this is possible by editing your code!  https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiBgv.jpg

Comment: @Hany Can you try to explain this in your question as precisely as possible. There are now three different options floating around: ovals, ellipses (which are some specific ovals) and the shapes depicted in [your screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0wHb.jpg), which are no ovals but have kinks. Anyone answering this question would probably need to know what you are really after.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I edited my question to clarify my need.